# MVC - On post the view model is not getting populated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

action method:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel blahblah)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (blahblah != null)
            {
                var obj = new tblPersonalDetail()
                {
                    FirstName = blahblah.FirstName,
                    LastName = blahblah.LastName,
                    Title = blahblah.Title,
                    Address = blahblah.Address,
                    Suburb = blahblah.Suburb,
                    HomePhone = blahblah.HomePhone,
                    Mobile = blahblah.Mobile,
                    Email = blahblah.Email,
                    EmergencyName = blahblah.EmergencyContactName,
                    EmergencyPhone = blahblah.EmergencyContactPhone,
                    EmergencyEmail = blahblah.EmergencyContactEmail,
                    EmergencyRelation = blahblah.EmergencyContactRelation,
                    DrivingLicenceExpiryDate = blahblah.DrivingLicenceExpiryDate,
                    DrivingLicenceNo = blahblah.DrivingLicenceNo,
                    DateofBirth = blahblah.DateofBirth
                };


                //if (uploadFile != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadFile.FileName))
                //{
                //    uploadFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath($@"~\Content\Images\{uploadFile.FileName}"));
                //    obj.ScannedImageLocation = ($@"~\Content\Images\{uploadFile.FileName}");
                //}
                db.tblPersonalDetails.Add(obj);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        return View(blahblah);
    }
```

--registerviewmodel

```
 public class RegisterViewModel
 {
    public string Title;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public string Address;
    public string Suburb;
    public string HomePhone;
    public string Mobile;
    public string Email;
    public string EmergencyContactName;
    public string EmergencyContactRelation;
    public string EmergencyContactPhone;
    public string EmergencyContactEmail;
    public string DrivingLicenceNo;
  //  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime DrivingLicenceExpiryDate;
    public string DrivingLicenceImage;
  //  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString ="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime DateofBirth;
    public string Notes;
    public string NextAppointment;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
        }
    }


}
```

the viewmodel on post is all null. if i use the tblPersonalDetail model class generated by the entityframework and then change the reference in the view (Register.cshtml), it posts with the data. However not with the custom view model.
--Register.cshtml

```
@model Leo.ViewModel.RegisterViewModel
@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Register New User";
 }
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="panel">

            <div class="panel-heading tabbable" tabindex="0"><h1>Personal Details</h1></div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, "Title", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <select class="form-control" id="Title">
                            <option>Mr</option>
                            <option>Mrs</option>
                            <option>Dr</option>
                            <option>Miss</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, "First Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, "Last Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, "Address", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Suburb, "Suburb", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Suburb, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HomePhone, "Home Phone", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HomePhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile, "Mobile", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobile, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, "Email", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-heading tabbable" tabindex="0"><h1>Emergency Details</h1></div>

            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmergencyContactName, "Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmergencyContactName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmergencyContactRelation, "Relation", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmergencyContactRelation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmergencyContactPhone, "Phone", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmergencyContactPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmergencyContactEmail, "Email", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmergencyContactEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="panel-heading tabbable" tabindex="0"><h1>Driving Licence Details</h1></div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DrivingLicenceNo, "Licence No", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DrivingLicenceNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DrivingLicenceExpiryDate, "Expiry Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DrivingLicenceExpiryDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DrivingLicenceImage, "Licence Image", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                       <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateofBirth, "Date of Birth", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateofBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>



                </div>

            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Notes</div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <textarea rows="10" cols="15" class="form-control" id="Notes"></textarea>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Invoice</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                        <label for="Paid">Paid</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Paid" placeholder="Amount Paid">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                        <label for="Balance">Balance</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Balance" placeholder="Balance">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                        <label for="Total">Total</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Total" placeholder="Total Amount">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="invoice.html" target="_blank">Print Invoice</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) not [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), you need to change your view model definition to have properties like:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
 {
    public string Title { get; set;}
    public string FirstName { get; set;}
    //............
    //............
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The default model binder in ASP.NET MVC will only bind to publicly accessible properties, however you are currently using fields, which will not be bound.

You'll just need to decorate them with the necessary getters / setters as seen below to make them into properties :

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{ 
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string FirstName  { get; set; }
     public string LastName  { get; set; }

     // Others omitted for brevity
}
```